# How to secure Plesk Admin Panel?

Tags: php, security, panel, recaptcha, plesk

I want to know how to secure the Plesk admin panel.
In fact, for acces to this admin panel, you must use this link : `https://<server ip address>:8443`

But there is no security, https is not activate, there is no recaptcha so hacker can use brute force ..

Have you any tips to secure all that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Plesk 12 there is a fail2ban* with "plesk-panel" jail which block password bruteforce attacks on admin panel.

Also you can install "Google Authenticator" to add two-factor authorization and "Clef Authentication" extension which replace plesk auth to auth with mobile phone.
Also there is old school "Restrict Administration Access" which just allows authorization for admin user(only) from white list of IP addresses

[image: plesk fail2ban, two-factor authoization]

`*` - fail2ban may be not installed or there is license restriction(check "License management" page for "fail2ban" option)

Comment: Thank you but I don't see "Restrict Admnistrative Acces" and "Fail2ban" in my settings

Comment: @Rocstar, fail2ban may be not installed or there is license restriction(check "License management" page for "fail2ban" option)

Comment: @Rocstar , "Restrict Administration Access" may be disabled/hidden in UI by your hosting provider, it should be always visible by default.